# Parcel multiple entry points for Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, parceljs

I'm creating a new Chrome extension. I introduced Parcel bundler for module bundling and TypeScript support.

I want build

```
/src
  /background-script
    index.ts
  /browser-action
    index.html
    index.ts
  /content-script
    index.ts
```

into

```
/dist
  /background-script
    index.js
  /browser-action
    index.html
    index.js
  /content-script
    index.js
```

`/src/index.html` imports `index.ts` in the same directory

```sh
parcel watch src/background-script/index.ts src/content-script/index.ts src/browser-action/index.html --no-hmr --out-dir dist --public-url .
```

This will produce following output:

```
/dist
  /background-script
    index.js
  /browser-action
    index.html
  /content-script
    index.js
  browser-action.***.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using something like this in package.json:

```
"build": "parcel build ./src/**/main.js ./src/**/main.scss --out-dir build --no-content-hash --no-source-maps",
```

It will take something like:

```
/src
  /project1
    /components
      utils.js
      constants.js
    main.js

  /project2
    main.js
```

In projects1 main.js is importing utils.js and constants.js and does some other stuff. Then the build command runs, it will minify, polyfill, transpile  into the main.js file in the /build folder.

And will generate a folder structure like:

```
/build
  /project1
    main.js
  /project2
    main.js
```

Comment: thanks, spent a couple of hours trying to understand how to watch multiple files and output them to multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Good news! Parcel 2 has a [transformer for WebExtensions](https://v2.parceljs.org/recipes/web-extension/):

`.parcelrc` file:

```json
{
    "extends": "@parcel/config-webextension"
}
```

Install command:

```
npm install parcel @parcel/config-webextension@next
```

Build command:

```
parcel build manifest.json

✨ Built in 1.18s
```

It will pick up every files mentioned in `manifest.json` plus some other files like what's under `_locales`